# "if" or "where" in for loop of arraylist in java?

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist, conditional-statements

I'm sorry if the question is a bit vague so i'll try to explain it.

I got this code:

```
    public String toString()
{
    String s = "text.\n";

    for (Klus k : alleKlussen)
    {
        s += k.toString() + ".\n";
    }
    return s;
}
```

But I want to make different loops for different conditions.
For example, "Klus" has a couple of variables like: status, date etc.

I'm not very experienced with java yet, but would it be possible to do something like this:

```
for (Klus k : alleKlussen; status = "completed")
{..}
```

I know this is wrong but I'd like it to show all "Klus" objects where the status is "completed" and all "Klus" objects where the statis is "not completed".

Thanks and if anything is unclear or I used the wrong word for something, please tell me.

Edit:

It should make something like this:

```
if (k.getStatus().equals("completed"){
  String s = "completed ones \n"
  s += k.toString() + ".\n"; //get all completed ones
}
if (k.getStatus().equals("uncompleted"){
      String s = "uncompleted ones \n"
      s += k.toString() + ".\n"; //get all uncompleted ones
    }
```

Comment: Please use a `StringBuilder` for iterative `String` concatenation! So much object burn...

Comment: Inside your for loop you'll just be wanting an `if` surely?

Comment: I think I explained it a bit wrong, I edited my question

Comment: your edit basically shows the answer.  I fail to see the question now.

Comment: What version of java you are using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply add the condition inside the `for()` loop:

```
for (Klus k : alleKlussen) {
    if (k.getStatus().equals("completed")) {
        s += k.toString() + ".\n";
    }
}
```

---

From the additional information in the question, it seems like the following is what is intended:

```
String completed = "completed ones \n";
String uncompleted = "uncompleted ones \n";

for (Klus k : alleKlussen) {

    if (k.getStatus().equals("completed")) {
      completed += k.toString() + ".\n"; //get all completed ones
    }
    else if (k.getStatus().equals("uncompleted")) {
       uncompleted += k.toString() + ".\n"; //get all uncompleted ones
    }
}
```

You should also consider using a [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) to create the result strings, which reduces the memory overhead.

Comment: Thanks! I forgot about the if statement but it's not exactly what I'm looking for, I think I explained it a bit wrong. I edited my question

Comment: This works for all completed ones, but how should i do the same for the uncompleted ones? just make another for-loop in the toString()?

Comment: @colin check my updated answer - is this what you need? You have two different Strings afterwards, containing information from completed and uncompleted objects. You could use two `for()` loops, but then you would need to iterate your list twice

Comment: Depending on what @colin needs, he could always just concatenate the two strings and return the result

Comment: Thanks, this did it for me. I just needed a list with the completed and uncompleted ones and this does just that!

Answer (score 2):

You can use switch if you have many conditions and it is easy to read

for (Klus k : alleKlussen)
{

```
switch(k.getStatus()){
       case "completed": ....
                          break;

       case "uncompleted": ....
                            break;

        default: ...
}
```

}

Please note [switch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) with String literals is only supported in Java 7.

Comment: Why, this would be a perfect case for enums, even if String literals are supported

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but how should it select only the "Klus" objects with "completed" in that case?

Comment: @Colin It is not possible to "just" get "Klus" objects depending on object status in this scenario. You need to iterate through the objects and check.

Comment: @Simon I agree, but in the original question the user is not using enums. He is using status as String literals.

Comment: I think this everntually also would've worked, but the other one was a bit more simple because I haven't learned to use cases yet. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Colin I appreciate that. If you have many statuses to be checked, you may find this solution simple to understand later on.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do the standard if-conditionals, such as:

```
if ("".equals(k.getStatus())) {

} else if ("completed".equals(k.getStatus())) {

}
```

Comment: A person with `20k` rep suggestion to use `==` for String value comparison? Unbelievable.

Comment: @R.J That wasn't my suggestion, my suggestion was to use a standard convention in most languages - if statements - the equality check was incidentally my lack of knowledge of Java _specifically_, but I don't think that detracts from the _actual_ suggestion. Unbelievably judgmental, maybe, as if you expect I got 20k rep in the [tag:Java].

Answer (score 0):

```
   Use this - this toString will print only Klus are completed.
 public String toString()
    {
        String s = "text.\n";

        for (Klus k : alleKlussen)
        {
            if("completed".equals(k.getStatus ()))
            s += k.toString() + ".\n";
        }
        return s;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To append the uncompleted after the completed ones, try this (And I suggest using enums, but you are welcome to stick to Strings. But then this will only work in Java SE 7!):

State.java:

```
// Makes switches easy to use and String typos are impossible
public enum State { COMPLETE, INCOMPLETE };
```

Replace your current String "state" with the enum like so:

Klus:java

```
public class Klus {
   private State state;
   ...
   public State getState() { return this.state; }
   ...
}
```

Now use it in a switch in the for loop. Use two strings, one for complete, one for incomplete. Append them in the end. (Note the use of **StringBuilder** instead of **str +=...** )

Class containing your toString():

```
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder complete = new StringBuilder("completed ones \n"), 
                  uncompleted = new StringBuilder("uncompleted ones \n");
    for(Klus k : alleKlussen) {
       switch(k.getStatus())
       case COMPLETE:
          complete.append(k.toString()).append(".\n"); break;
       case INCOMPLETE:
          uncompleted.append(k.toString()).append(".\n"); break;
       default:
       }
    }

    complete.append(uncompleted.toString();

    return complete.toString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I see a lot of things I haven't heard about yet. But maybe in the final version I could also use this method for the statuses. Thanks.

Comment: @colin you're welcome. Andreas' answer helps you out without all the extra bells and whistles, though :-D Have fun coding!